# Print Window for every single record into new page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to print every single record in new page using javascript:window.print() and css

example :

Name        : Demo1
Fathers Name: Demo Father1
Address     : Sample1
Phone       : 1234567891

Name        : Demo2
Fathers Name: Demo Father2
Address     : Sample2
Phone       : 1234567892

Name        : Demo3
Fathers Name: Demo Father3
Address     : Sample3
Phone       : 1234567893

i want every user details into new page means single user address in single page can any one help me plzzz